# Can I split reputation gained from a featured question?

Tags: discussion

I got points answering the following question:
[How to check for the distribution stability?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189833/how-to-check-for-the-distribution-stability/)

As commented bellow the answer, a different answer that included the main points was answered a day before.

How can I split the points gained with the other user?

Answer (score 9):

This has a short answer: You can't.

If it wasn't already the smallest possible bounty, you could perhaps offer a smaller bounty yourself, and award it to the other answer, but as it stands you can't do much other than vote for the other answer.

Comment: Thanks. Well, at least I voted for that answer.

Comment: @Dan I wouldn't worry too much -- your answer was actually a bit different (different enough to be worth posting I think), and clearly preferable to the OP. The other answerer does seem somewhat bothered by it but I don't see all that much to be bothered about, personally.

Comment: @Dan I have devised a solution to the splitting problem in this particular instance.

Comment: That's great, Glen. What is the solution?

Comment: It has already been applied: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189833/how-to-check-for-the-distribution-stability/ ... but it will take a day

Comment: Oh, you gave bounty to the same answer and you'll give the points to the other answer? It is both clever and nice. Thanks you very much!

Comment: I placed a second bounty on the question, yes; I wouldn't have done so ordinarily (it doesn't quite meet my usual standard for a bounty), but since you sought to share it, and I could make something similar happen, I figured I would do so.

Comment: It is indeed quite unusual. Thanks again! ;-)